# Some issues about how to JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am pretty new to databases and I have the following question: I have 2 tables `Cpe` and `CpeVendor`.

`Cpe` have the following columns:

```
Id                   int
Cpe                  varchar
SourceId             varchar
DateAdded            datetime
vendor_id            int
Title            varchar
part             char
product_id           int
version          varchar
revision             varchar
edition          varchar
language             varchar
```

And `CpeVendor` has the following columns:

```
id               int
nome             varchar
date_added       datetime
```

So a single row in the `Cpe` table is related to a single row in `CpeVendor` table but a single row in `CpeVendor` could be related to multiple rows in `Cpe` table

My problem is that I want see the two tables as a single table in which the rows of `Cpe` table are related to the rows in `CpeVendor` binding together the value of the `vendor_id` column of `Cpe` with the `id` value in the `CpeVendor` table

I think that I have to do a `JOIN` operation, is it right? Can you help me to perform this operation?

Comment: What you are asking is very basic.  That being the case, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic join statement to return all columns from both tables joined by the vendor_id:

```
SELECT C.*, CV.* FROM Cpe C
     INNER JOIN CpeVendor CV ON C.vendor_id = CV.id
```

The `C` and `CV` after each table are aliases that provide shortened references to each table. Everywhere else in the SQL you can use then `C.` and `CV.` to refer to those tables.

Take a look here for useful basics on writing queries: [Technet SQL Query guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM CpeVendor cv join 
     cpe c on c.vendor_id = cv.id
```

Assuming that Vendor_ID is the FK of ID from the CpeVendor Table.

This will return all the columns from both tables where there is a match between vendor_id = cv.id .